Image Creation via nested serializer field
MODELS:
class Product(models.Model):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'name', unique=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null= True)
    product_profile_image = VersatileImageField(blank=True, null= True, upload_to= 'images/product_profile')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = VersatileImageField(blank=True, null= True, upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"image of {self.product.name}"

SERIALIZERS:
class ImageSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['uuid','image']



class ListCreateProductSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    images = ImageSerializer(many= True, required=False, source='image_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['uuid', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'product_profile_image', 'quantity', 'images']


    def create(self, validated_data):
        images = validated_data.pop('images', [])
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for image in images:
            Image.objects.create(product=product, image=image)

        return product



VIEWS:
class ListCreateProductView(ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = ListCreateProductSerializer
permission_classes = [ShopPermission]

def get_queryset(self):
    shop_uuid = self.kwargs.get('shop_uuid')
    shop = get_object_or_404(Shop, uuid=shop_uuid)

    products = Product.objects.filter(shop=shop)
    if not products:
        raise NotFound(detail="This shop does not have any products")

    return products

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    shop_uuid= self.kwargs.get('shop_uuid')
    shop = get_object_or_404(Shop, uuid=shop_uuid)
    product = serializer.save(shop=shop)
    return product

When I upload images in POSTMAN, no new images are being created or associated with the new product instance.
Please Help
I tried this
# images = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField(), required=False, write_only= True)
that worked, but i had to make it write_only, so i can't view the images for already created products

After analyzing your data models, Product should have a one-to-many relationship with Image and not the other way around.

Please fix the formatting in the question
